# velocity vectors between different coordinate systems in differential geometry

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-spaces

I am reading GTM 93, Dubrovin's Modern Geometry Part 1. On page 13, it reads

> Suppose that in Euclidean n-space with Euclidean coordinates $(x^1,\dots,x^n)$, we are given a new system of (not necessarily Euclidean) coordinates $(z^1,\dots,z^n)$, and that $x^i=x^i(z^1,\dots,z^n), i=1,\dots,n$. Suppose also that we are given a curve whose parametric equations in terms of the new coordinates are: $z^i=z^i(t),i=1,\dots,n$. Then we can get from these a parametrization of the curve in terms of the original, Euclidean, coordinates, namely $x^j=x^j(z(t))=h^j(t), j=1,\dots,n$. We define the velocity or tangent vector of the curve relative to the coordinates $(z^1,\dots,z^n)$ to be the vector $v_z(t)=(v_z^1,\dots,v_z^n)$, where $v_z^j=dz^j/dt,j=1,\dots,n$. Relative to the original coordinates $(x^1,\dots,x^n)$, the tangent vector is $v=v_x=(dh^1/dt,\dots,dh^n/dt)$. The vectors $v_z(t)$ and $v_x(t)$ are actually the same vector since each of them is the velocity (relative to $t$) at which the curve is being traced out, evaluated at the point $P$, represented by $(z^1(t),\dots,z^n(t))$ in the new coordinate system, and by $(h^1(t),\dots,h^n(t))$ in the old.

And later the authors use the relation $|v_z|^2=|v_x|^2$, which is the place I don't understand. For, if in 1-space we take $$z(t)=t$$ $$x(z(t))=2z=2t=h(t)$$ then we have $$v_z=dz/dt=1$$ $$v_x=dh/dt=2.$$ In this case, evidently the relation $|v_z|^2=|v_x|^2$ is not satisfied. Where is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that they have that the norm is different with the change of coordinates. Or rather, that the norm is independent of the coordinates.
The norm is a function
$$
| \cdot | : \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R
$$

This function in Euclidean coordinates will be the usual norm, which may be represented by the identity matrix $I$ in the form
$$
|v_x|^2 = v_x^t I v_x = \sum_i (v_x^i)^2.
$$
($v^t$ is the transpose.)

But in different coordinates $z$ you'll have that the matrix representation will be different
$$
|v_z|^2 = v_z^t G v_z
$$
for some different matrix $G$.

$G$ will be something like $A^t I A$ for the change of basis matrix $A$ which takes you from $x$ coordinates to $z$ coordinates
$$(v_z)^j = A^j_i (v_x)^i$$
(Or maybe the other way around $v_x = A v_z$ you'll have to check whichever way makes $|v_x|=|v_z|$.)

In your example, since the coordinates scale by 2, the norm will scale by 1/2 to compensate.